# Updating ImpromptuInterface from 6.2.2 to 7.0.1 (latest version)

Tags: c#, impromptu-interface

My project currently references **ImpromptuInterface 6.2.2** and it works great. I am in the process of updating all my nuget packages to latest version.

When updating ImpromptuInterface from 6.2.2 to 7.0.1 I got 2 errors:

- *'Impromptu' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeGet'*
- *'Impromptu' does not contain a definition for 'GetMemberNames'*

My code:

```
if (Impromptu.GetMemberNames(sourceObject).Any(x => x == newPropertyPath))
{
    var newSourceObject = Impromptu.InvokeGet(sourceObject, newPropertyPath);
}
```

It seems these methods does no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the methods in [ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) that you are using have been moved to a different library, [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/tree/master/Dynamitey).  ImpromptuInterface depends on Dynamitey, so Dynamitey should have been added to your project as part of the ImpromptuInterface upgrade.

Try replacing `ImpromptuInterface.InvokeGet` with `Dynamic.InvokeGet` and `ImpromptuInterface.GetMemberNames` with `Dynamic.GetMemberNames`.  You might need to add a line `using Dynamitey;` as well.

Comment: I'll try that asap and keep you informed. Thanks !